gcc-14 c++20 chrono timezone functions getting deleted
I need a specific C++20 feature only implemented in gcc-14 thusfar. I installed GCC via brew, I'm compiling like this, just to be absolutely sure:
/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-14 -std=c++20 -isystem /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0_1/include/c++/14/ test.cpp -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0_1/lib/gcc/14 -stdlib=libstdc++. And it's giving errors like
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/14.2.0_1/include/c++/14/bits/stl_construct.h:119:7: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr std::chrono::time_zone_link::time_zone_link(const std::chrono::time_zone_link&)'. This timezone functionality is implemented, it says so here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20 under 'calendar and timezone'. I am reading the <chrono> header, I see get_tzdb, it is defining it and getting 'deleted'. I don't understand what this means or why it's happening. This is on AArch64.

We need to see what you have in test.cpp too

Of course, I will add it, but it's just calling get_tzdb that does it.

From the documentation: "time_zone_link is not copyable ...".  So my guess is your code is trying to copy a std::chrono::time_zone_link somewhere.

When asking questions about build errors, always include a [mre] and a full and complete copy-paste of the build log. Both copy-pasted as text of course. Format both as code snippets.

Actually yes I just realized it too, I was assigning get_tzdb, it works without assigning it. Very strange! Thanks.

@olafwx Just calling get_tzdb is no problem. Are you sure you are not trying to copy the result? This is what we need to see.

get_tzdb returns a reference. This is for a reason.

The database tzdb, returned by get_tzdb() is not copy constructible nor copy assignable.  It is movable, but you only have const access to it so you can't move it either.  You can only hold a reference to it.
This reason for this design is the database is a singleton in your program.  Or more precisely, there exists a singly linked list of tzdb that is a singleton, and get_tzdb() will give you a reference to the head of that list.
The database is a large object that many threads will need a const view of to retrieve time zone information.  It would be bad if the database got moved or copied around.  This would cause thread safety issues.
